# Templatize stream operator for printing enumerations

Tags: c++, templates

I have a namespace that creates a series of enums used through my application with associated print statements, like so:

```
namespace NS {
    enum EnumA { A1, A2, A3 };
    enum EnumB { B1, B2, B3 };

    inline std::string toString(const EnumA key) {
        switch(key) {
        case A1: return "A1";
        case A2: return "A2";
        case A3: return "A3";
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }

    // .. same for EnumB
}

// this is the part I would like to templatize
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const NS::EnumA key) {
    s << NS::toString(key);
    return s;
}
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const NS::EnumB key) {
    s << NS::toString(key);
    return s;
}
```

Is it possible to templatize the stream operator to work with any `NS` enum so I only have to have one? Like:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const NS::<T> key) {
    s << NS::toString(key);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only things in namespace `NS` are toString-capable types, you can put your `operator<<` in the namespace, thusly:

```
namespace NS {
  enum EnumA { A1, A2, A3 };
  enum EnumB { B1, B2, B3 };

  inline std::string toString(const EnumA key) {
    ...
  }
  inline std::string toString(const EnumB key) {
    ...
  }

  template <typename T>
  inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const T key) {
    std::operator << (s, NS::toString(key));
    return s;
  }

}
```

A complete program is [here](http://ideone.com/ru9YA).

Comment: I don't know how that works, but it does, especially since printing to the stream directly doesn't work (even if it is in the namespace).

Answer (score 3):

The obvious approach will result in your overload being considered for all types; this will result in calls being ambiguous for all types, since templates are not choosy.  So you need some way to tell the compiler that your `enum` is the right type of `enum`, and to ignore all the rest; a traits class is probably the easiest way to do that.

```
namespace NS {
  enum EnumA { };

  template<typename T>
  struct is_ns_enum : std::false_type { };

  template<>
  struct is_ns_enum<EnumA> : std::true_type { };
}
```

From there, you can use SFINAE to implement your function.

```
template<typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<is_ns_enum<T>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator <<(std::ostream& s, const T&) {
  ...
}
```

This way, the overload is considered for any types you specialize `is_ns_enum` for, but is discarded for all other types, preventing that slew of ambiguous overload errors.

Comment: +1 That seems to work, however, I end up writing the same amount of code, which I always forget to do, hence wanting a template.

Answer (score 1):

If you templatize the stream type as well, this will work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace NS {
    enum EnumA { A1, A2, A3 };
    enum EnumB { B1, B2, B3 };

inline std::string toString(const EnumA key) {
        switch(key) {
        case A1: return "A1";
        case A2: return "A2";
        case A3: return "A3";
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }

inline std::string toString(const EnumB key) {
        switch(key) {
        case B1: return "B1";
        case B2: return "B2";
        case B3: return "B3";
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
};

template <class Stream, typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(Stream& s, T key) {
    s << NS::toString(key);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << NS::A2;
    cout << NS::B3;
}
```